# How to check if localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way in c# to check if the app is running on localhost (as opposed to a production server)?

I am writing a mass mailing program that needs to use a certain mail queue is it's running on localhost.

```
if (Localhost)
{
Queue = QueueLocal;
}
else
{
Queue = QueueProduction;
}
```

Comment: A web app is always running on localhost :)

Comment: Why not use some sort of configuration-based value that specifies the correct queue?

Comment: It will run where it has been assigned to, if you dont know anything about backend then you cant find where the application is running.However any running application must be having its own system known as its localhost.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a value in the application configuration file that will tell you what environment you are on.

Since you are using asp.net, you can utilize [config file transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx) to ensure the setting is correct for each of your environments.

Comment: Interesting, but I didn't think I could store variables inside of a web.config, can I?  Right now the path to the mail queue is a string inside the mailer service.

Comment: @user547794 - `web.config` is all about variability. And I linked to config transform documentation. I suggest reading that so you can see how much you can do.

Answer (score 83):

As a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11834122/112397) has the correct solution I'm going to post it as an answer:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal
```

Answer (score 36):

What about something like:

```
public static bool OnTestingServer()
    {
        string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower();
        return (host == "localhost");
    }
```

Comment: Although looking at the big picture, Oded's solution is likely what I would lean more towards than simply checking local host.

Comment: Request.Url.Host  can return something else, like 127.0.0.1.  Just do HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal

Comment: it's better to avoid dependency to HttpContext if you want your code IIS-independent...

Answer (score 21):

See if this works:

```
public static bool IsLocalIpAddress(string host)
{
  try
  { // get host IP addresses
    IPAddress[] hostIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
    // get local IP addresses
    IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

    // test if any host IP equals to any local IP or to localhost
    foreach (IPAddress hostIP in hostIPs)
    {
      // is localhost
      if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(hostIP)) return true;
      // is local address
      foreach (IPAddress localIP in localIPs)
      {
        if (hostIP.Equals(localIP)) return true;
      }
    }
  }
  catch { }
  return false;
}
```

Reference: http://www.csharp-examples.net/local-ip/

Comment: Don't we need to test the *client" for a local connection, ie the source of a current connection resolves to the localhost IP.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there is no [`HttpContext.HttpRequest.IsLocal()`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/2476c4476218262fed4ab28e0f4cc17885b2df2b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/DefaultHttpRequest.cs) anymore within core.

But after checking the [original implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/WorkerRequest.cs,ab8517882440da8b) in .Net, it is quite easy to reimplement the same behaviour by checking [`HttpContext.Connection`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/2476c4476218262fed4ab28e0f4cc17885b2df2b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/DefaultHttpContext.cs#L118):

```
private bool IsLocal(ConnectionInfo connection)
{
    var remoteAddress = connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

    // if unknown, assume not local
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteAddress))
        return false;

    // check if localhost
    if (remoteAddress == "127.0.0.1" || remoteAddress == "::1")
        return true;

    // compare with local address
    if (remoteAddress == connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString())
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: And here's how to access the HTTPContext from an asp.net CORE 2 application:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components

Comment: It's works good. Maybe in feature versions extension methods or helpers will be added to .NET Core to handle this validation from the box.

Comment: LocalIpAddress for some reason is null on Linux behind nginx reverse proxy.

Answer (score 7):

Localhost ip address is constant, you can use it to determines if it´s localhost or remote user.

But beware, if you are logged in the production server, it will be considered localhost too.

This covers IP v.4 and v.6:

```
public static bool isLocalhost( )
{
    string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    return (ip == "127.0.0.1" || ip == "::1");
}
```

To be totally sure in which server the code is running at, you can use the MAC address:

```
public string GetMACAddress()
{
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    String sMacAddress = string.Empty;
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
        if (sMacAddress == String.Empty)// only return MAC Address from first card  
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
            sMacAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
        }
    } return sMacAddress;
}
```

from: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ahsanm.m/how-to-get-the-mac-address-of-system-using-Asp-NetC-Sharp/

And compare with a MAC address in web.config for example.

```
public static bool isLocalhost( )
{
    return GetMACAddress() == System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalhostMAC"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could use a [C# Preprocessor Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) if your simply targeting a development environment (this is assuming your app doesn't run in debug in production!):

```
#if debug
Queue = QueueLocal;
#else
Queue = QueueProduction;
```

Answer (score 1):

just like this:

HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal

Comment: straight up the best one

Answer (score 1):

I know this is the really old thread but still, someone looking for a straight solution then you can use this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host == "localhost")
{
  //your action when app is running on localhost
}
```

Comment: ... which already exists as an answer since August 2012

Comment: if you want I can delete it :) #nooffence

Answer (score 0):

string hostName = Request.Url.Host.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative, more transparent, option:

```
public static bool IsLocal
{
    // MVC < 6
    get 
    {
        var authority = HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority.ToLower();

        return authority == "localhost" ||
               authority.StartsWith("localhost:");
    }
    // MVC 6+
    get 
    { 
        return String.Compare(HttpContext.Request.Url.Host, "localhost", 
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

If you're **not** doing this in the `Controller` then add  `Current` after `HttpContext`, as in `HttpContext.Current.Request...`

Also, in `MVC 6`, in the `View`, `HttpContext` is just `Context`